# SQL Query to combine two select statements and create a view - answered by SNL

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query that contains a pending assignment task. The pending assignment table contain rows "new drug" and "current drug" that reference to the same drug dose row in another table. When I run a query like below, I get no results (notice that I am joining both the new and current drug to the same row dose ID:

```
SELECT D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Station_Id,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Cabinet_Num,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Drawer_Num,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Pocket_Num,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Assignment_Type,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Requested_By,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Requested_Dttm,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Current_Drug_Dose_Id,
   AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Display_Name,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.New_Drug_Dose_Id 
   FROM CRX_DATA.dbo.D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN,
   CRX_DATA.dbo.AHI_DRUG_DOSE AHI_DRUG_DOSE
   WHERE (D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Current_Drug_Dose_Id =
       AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Dose_Id)
   OR (D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.New_Drug_Dose_Id =
           AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Dose_Id)
```

However, when I run them separately, I get the desired results. See below:

```
SELECT D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Station_Id,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Cabinet_Num,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Drawer_Num,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Pocket_Num,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Assignment_Type,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Requested_By,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Requested_Dttm,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Current_Drug_Dose_Id,
   AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Display_Name
FROM CRX_DATA.dbo.D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN,
   CRX_DATA.dbo.AHI_DRUG_DOSE AHI_DRUG_DOSE
WHERE (D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Current_Drug_Dose_Id =
       AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Dose_Id)
```

---

```
SELECT D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Station_Id,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Cabinet_Num,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Drawer_Num,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Pocket_Num,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Assignment_Type,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Requested_By,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Requested_Dttm,
   AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Display_Name,
   D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.New_Drug_Dose_Id
FROM CRX_DATA.dbo.D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN,
   CRX_DATA.dbo.AHI_DRUG_DOSE AHI_DRUG_DOSE
WHERE (D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.New_Drug_Dose_Id = AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Dose_Id)
```

---

I would like to know if there is a way to create a view by combining the two select queries into one?

Thank you

Comment: What is the structure of the table that you want?  You're going to have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `AND` to `OR` in your `WHERE` clause in the first query?

Comment: JNK - thank you! If I just did that, I would have answered my own question! That was it and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query, as written, will not likely work.

```
WHERE (D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Current_Drug_Dose_Id =          AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Dose_Id)   
AND (D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.New_Drug_Dose_Id =            AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Dose_Id)
```

You are asking SQL to find a record in the AHI_DRUG_DOSE table with the field Drug_Dose_ID equal to both the Current_drug_dose_id and the New_Drug_dose_Id.    Unless those ID's are the same, it is not possible to have one field contain both values...

Try this instead.

```
WHERE (D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.Current_Drug_Dose_Id =          AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Dose_Id)   
OR (D_PENDING_POCKET_ASSIGN.New_Drug_Dose_Id =            AHI_DRUG_DOSE.Drug_Dose_Id)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you change the `AND` to an `OR` in your `WHERE` clause you should get the desired result set.